# expand table and copy formula down

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel Table **there is already some data** in a column.
Now I write a formula into the last row of that table and expand the table.
In the new row (row 10 in the picture) the formula is not expandet from row 9 to 10.
This is normal because not all cells in the column have the same formula.

**Is there a way to expand the last cells formula down when expanding the table?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether following information is helpful.

On my simple sample, the formula is `=IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2,$E$2:$F$13,2,FALSE),"")`.

[image]

Then I apply the formula to a larger range. If there is a new data in ID column, then the formula will search the data, otherwise, the data is shown as empty.

[image]

Comment: I know this possibility. Thank you. But I mean in a table.